# ispconfig php-fpm SSL error with large file

Tags: php, upload, ispconfig

When I upload a big file, it stops for a long time and responds with this error:

```
has expired: ... AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade) ...
```

I saw that on server the file is nearly uploaded, only few bytes remaining, but it stops receiving. Maybe it checks the file in memory finding the type and stops.

more here: [phpinfo](https://6.it.cx/phpinfo.pdf)

php code like in [example code: upload.php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: There's no code here, just an error and links to a PDF which doesn't have a valid SSL certificate and a link to W3 Schools. I think this is too localized.

Comment: This php code from w3school executes with no problem uploading small files, but when I tried to upload a big file the above error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix SSLRenegBufferSize to your need in apache2 configuration

in **apache2 sites-enabled conf** file add the following line inside `<Directory ...>` brackets :

```
"SSLRenegBufferSize 1024000" or more
```

Comment: Can you make your answer more specific/detailed? Fix it "how" and with "what" syntax/setting?

Comment: I think now it's ok, isn't it?